# Esconder link do youtube

Tags: html, youtube

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de videos cursos.
Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de pegar um video do youtube, e colocar no site de uma maneira que o usuário não consiga(dificulte) visualizar o link do youtube, para que não possa compartilhar com outras pessoas.
Obrigado!

Comment: Baixar o vídeo e fazer o upload no seu site...

Comment: Torne o vídeo privado no Youtube e libere acesso apenas para os usuários que deseja que possam ver. Depois chore de raiva e corte os pulsos quando o primeiro deles descobrir um plugin de navegador que permite baixar o seu vídeo. Você só vai conseguir "dificultar" pros usuários se eles tiverem mais de 50 anos de idade e não souberem a diferença entre 'Internet' e 'Internet Explorer'.

Comment: "O meu objetivo com a proposta de inabilitar a possibilidade do usuário chegar ao YouTube, é de manter o conteúdo protegido." Isso soa como "O meu objetivo em levar a gasolina num saco plástico até o carro ao invés de deixar meu cliente ir ao posto, é de manter a gasolina protegida."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode desabilitar as opções do YouTube, como o header e rodapé com o logo e bloquear a ação do botão direito. É claro, mesmo assim o usuário terá acesso ao link via inspecionar elemento.

Trabalhar com streaming é complicado pois apesar de você blindar, como os dados estão trafegando até a maquina do usuário, existem formas de capturar. Como por exemplo, Real Player ou certas extensões do Firefox.

Comment: Mas pelo código fonte teria total acesso!

Comment: Exato, como eu mesmo comentei acima. A questão é que mesmo blindando o código fonte, a pessoa consegue capturar o conteúdo transmitido via streaming. Uma única pergunta. Será que seria tão necessário assim você criar essa proteção? Já pensou se o publico alvo teria intenção de compartilhar ou até mesmo conhecimento para tal?

Comment: São cursos de EAD!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criptografar o link, e colocar um script PHP para desencriptar o link e redirecionar o usuario dentro deste, assim a pessoa vera um link tipo redir.php?id=xmslskdS0dd1....

Answer (score 0):

Sai mais fácil colocar em host de videos pagos, indicando URL onde pode ser exibido, mesmo assim precisa colocar senhas em cada vídeo, caso alguém baixe por aplicativos precisa descobri a senha.
Veja um exemplo no vímeo: https://vimeo.com/344205263 (Quando solicitado a senha: novato)