# Incorporar um vídeo privado do meu canal no Youtube em meu site

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Gostaria de incorporar em meu site um vídeo definido como **privado** que está no meu canal do youtube.

Lendo a [documentação do Youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) acredito que seja a [API de dados](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#data_api) ou a [API de Player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#player_apis)

Meu objetivo é fazer com que possam ver o vídeo/*livestream* apenas a partir do meu site, até mesmo "forçando" o usuário a visitar minha página, mesmo que ele tenha o link do vídeo.

Comment: Com vídeos privados não será possível, mas se usar vídeos `não listados` poderá fazer sem problemas. E o vídeo estará "privado" no sentido de que não pode ser encontrado no YouTube.

Comment: Sim amigo, mas desta forma a galera pode inspecionar elemento e obter o url do respectivo canal. Mas uma alternativa seria usar desta forma e talvez com um flash encapsular o url. No entanto isso ficaria pouco dinâmico.

Comment: Não será [isto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17085/esconder-link-do-youtube) que procura?

Comment: Faça uma conta premium no Vimeo e já está...

Comment: @IagoLeão, neste caso sua única alternativa e' criar uma segunda conta no YouTube e acessar o vídeo pelo seu website por CURL ou tentar outra plataforma como: http://www.vidmeup.com/ ou Vimeo premium como o brasofilo mencionou.

Comment: Encontrei [esse stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612000/using-the-youtube-api-v3-to-list-all-private-videos) no SO Inglês que *aparentemente* faz aquilo que você precisa, no entanto, requer usar um componente do Zend Framework. Vale a tentativa e, caso funcione, apesra de não ser o dieal reinventar a roda, você pode experimentar codificar por você mesmo e reproduzir aquilo que o componente do framework faz pois, ao que deu pra entender, contanto que você se autentique com uma conta que tenha permissão de ver os vídeos, já basta.

Comment: Vimeo Premium é uma boa solução, no entanto ele tem suporte a liveStream?

Comment: @Kyllopardiun hoje não dar mais para acessar o youtube com Curl, eles criaram um check_config embutido na pagina do form e no nomento que submete o posto o servidor valida e ignora o que não esta válido.

Comment: Já pensou em colocar o vídeo diretamente no seu site, sem YouTube ou outro?

Comment: @lagoLeão não entendi algo, porque o usuário nao pode inspecionar elemento e descobrir o canal? se não quiser pagar e usar o youtube seria mais facil criar outro canal só com videos não listados.

Answer (score 2):

A solução que encontrei foi:

1) Mudar a configuração do vídeo de privado para não listado.

2) Criar um flash para encapsular e ocultar transmitir o vídeo do Youtube. Sendo que o Flash chama um PHP que trás a URL do vídeo se a requisição for aceita. Isso serve para se o cara descompilar o flash não saber qual o URL do mesmo.

Comment: Isso não vai facilitar a vida do cara? Agora só o que ele tem que fazer é baixar o swf e rodar onde quiser. Certo? Edit: Errado, o php cuida disso.

Comment: Não sei se isso vai ajudar muito, o aTube Catcher tem uma função que grava um vídeo diretamente da tela, quero dizer, só apontar a parte da tela para gravar e ele o faz.

Comment: E este PHP que trás a URL do vídeo? alguém teria um exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o seguinte :

Acesse seu Gerenciador de vídeos.

Localize o vídeo que deseja alterar e clique no botão Editar.

No menu suspenso "Configurações de privacidade", selecione  Não listado

Clique em Salvar alterações.

Com isso ele não sera listado no seu canal para a pessoa poder ver o vídeo ela ira precisar usar o link quando você for adicionar o video em seu site passe o link para o player que com certeza dará certo.

Comment: Como mencionei acima, desta forma o usuário pode inspecionar elemento e visualizar. A intenção não é esta.