# É possível exibir vídeos privados pela API do Youtube?

Tags: api, youtube

Estou criando uma estratégia de conteúdo para um cliente e a seguinte necessidade surgiu: Exibir vídeos privados do canal do youtube no site.

O que pretendemos fazer é criar uma estratégia onde os usuários só possam ver alguns dos vídeos do canal dentro do site do nosso cliente, tipo conteúdo exclusivo, entendem? Existe todo um discurso de suporte à essa estratégia, que não vem ao caso comentar aqui, pois seria só bla-bla-bla.

Minha dúvida: É possível trazer vídeos privados do Youtube para o site somente utilizando a API do Youtube? Não quero um "how to", só preciso mesmo saber se é possível. Olhei a documentação, mas não consegui esclarecer muito essa dúvida.

Obrigado à todos!

Comment: Duplicada de [Incorporar um vídeo privado do meu canal no Youtube em meu site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19052/incorporar-um-v%C3%ADdeo-privado-do-meu-canal-no-youtube-em-meu-site).

Comment: Eu tenho conhecimento que no site https://vimeo.com tem essa possibilidade! http://developer.vimeo.com

Comment: Pois é, o problema é que o canal do usuário já está hospedado no You Tube, sendo assim, a opção de passa-lo pro Vimeo não seria viável.

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com o guia de referência da API 3.0

http://api-portal.anypoint.mulesoft.com/youtube/api/youtube-data-api-v30/docs/reference

"In addition, some API methods for retrieving resources may support parameters that require authorization or may contain additional metadata when requests are authorized. For example, a request to retrieve a user's uploaded videos may also contain private videos if the request is authorized by that specific user."

Comment: Valeu, cara! =)

Acabei descobrindo a existência dos vídeos "não listados", que podem me ajudar.
Conversei com um amigo meu sobre o assunto no fim de semana e ele comentou dessa possibilidade, mas disse que precisava dessa autorização pro acesso aos vídeos.